# Handling of arrays of pointers in c++ and deleting them

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have created a test class (tc) which holds an array pointers to int.

```
class TC
{
public:
    int **values;
    TC(){values = new int*[10];
 };
```

When I instatiate an instance and do the following changes:

```
TC *a = new TC();    
int **values = &*a->values;
int **oldvalues = values;
values = new int*[10];
values[0] = oldvalues[0];
...
values[9] = oldvalues[9];

delete [] oldvalues;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    delete values[i];
}

delete [] values;
```

Now comes the interesting part:

```
values = new int*[10];
*a->values = *values;

values[0] = new int(1);
values[9] = new int(10);
std::cout << *values[0] << " " << *values[9];
```

This prints out

1 10

But switching the two lines

```
values = new int*[10];
*a->values = *values;
```

to

```
*a->values = *new int*[10];    
values = &*a->values;
```

prints

182939382 10

Where the first part is some pointer.

Can someone explain why this happens? What makes the difference between the two ways to handle the pointers?

EDIT:
I'd appreciate constructive input. As you might be able to tell I don't have any experience with c++ and pointer handling. So please help me understand the errors that I am committing.

Comment: If you don't know why immediately dereferencing the result of `new` is a bad idea (as in `*new T[n]`), then you aren't ready to work with multiple indirection yet.

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson.

Comment: `&*a->values` - what do you think this means?

Comment: @kotlomoy: That's a bad sign too, but it's just *silly*, and I chose to first focus on the things that are definitely *wrong*.

Comment: @kotlomoy: I was intending to get the address of the first array element and assigning this address to the int** values.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, I just want to know what OP thinks about it. I suspect fundamental misunderstanding of pointers concept. If so, then your answer just makes no sense for him anyway.

Comment: @caldis Well... Operator `*` takes a pointer and returns value wich pointer point to. Quite to the contrary, operator `&` takes a value and returns a pointer to this value. These operators are inverse. Therefore `&*a->values` is equal to `a->values`. It's just like changing the sign of number twice - has no effect.

Comment: @caldis seems you are leaving out much of TC so your example code seems to assume things that you are not showing making it difficult to help. e.g. is values in TC allocated in constructor?

Comment: @kotlomoy: i understand. But if i read c++ Operator precedence corrently the expression would be equal to &(*a->values). Am I wrong?

Comment: @claptrap: you are right. I added the constructor to post.

Comment: @caldis Apparently you missed the whole point of my comment... I repeat: `*` and `&` operators are *inverse* (may be this is wrong word? I don't speak English, sorry). It means that these operators undo each other. It doesn't matter how you write, `&*a->values` or `&(*a->values)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is to long for you skip to the *tldr* part at the bottom, but that wont help you understand the problems, for that you need to read the rest.

---

my c is rusty but there are some highly strange parts:

lets start with this:

```
TC *a = new TC();    
int **values = &*a->values;
int **oldvalues = values;
values = new int*[10];
values[0] = oldvalues[0];
...
values[9] = oldvalues[9];

delete [] oldvalues;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    delete values[i];
}

delete [] values;
```

---

```
TC *a = new TC();
```

Perfectly fine

```
int **values = &*a->values;
```

lets look at the second half `&*a->values;`, step by step

```
  a              //pointer to tc
  a->values      //access values member of the tc a points to
                 //this is a int**
 *a->values      //dereference the int**, so we have a int*  
&*a->values;     //get the address of int*, so we have int** again
```

in short as stated in the comments you could just write `a->values.`
Lets look further, you seem to be using int** to hold a pointer to an array of int pointers.

Now what does `int **values = a->values;` come down to? You copy a *pointer*, this means that `**values` and `a->values` now refer to the same address (slightly off, but for now consider Arrays as a pointer to the first element, that have to be defered with the index operator `[]`, otherwise they refer to the first element). This means you point to the same Array twice

values    \
           \
           |- Array created by TC(){values = new int*[10];
           /
a->values /

```
int **oldvalues = values;
```

Basically you create a third pointer to the same array, for what reason?

```
values = new int*[10];
```

Here you *overwrite* `values` before you read once from it when initializing it to `a->values`.

```
values[0] = oldvalues[0];
...
values[9] = oldvalues[9];
```

noticing that you have two pointers you now copy the data. A loop or a function to copy chunks of memory could ease this, but I recommend a stl class, check out [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) from the stl.

```
delete [] oldvalues;
```

you delete `oldvalues`, which is deleting the array that your `TC`-Class uses.
While one needs to delete what one creates with new, this can be hell, if `TC`'s `destructor` tries to delete the array as well (though shall not call `delete` multiple times for the same object). Furthermore since your class seems to assume that `values` is alwazs valid, why not overwrite the values in the array?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    delete values[i];
}
delete [] values;
```

you remember to delete all the integers before you delete the array, this is good, but why not overwrite them? Besides, this should be handled by the destructor as well, if you write one (you SHOULD). BUt what is dubious, why do you copy the elements, just to delete them?

FUrthermore, why don"t you use an integer array? is an array of pointers to integers really necessary?

This would be an int array [1, 2, 3, 7].
While this is an array of pointers: [see 1, see 2, see 4, see 5], in addition you have the following numbers at the following memory addresses 1@1, 2@2, 3@4, 7@5

For the array of pointers you have to do the following to get to a number:

```
*arrayOfPointers[3]
```

This does the following:

1. the value of the `4th` (for indexing start counting at 0) array element, `see 5` is loaded
2. the value is dereferenced which means the computer looks in the memory location with the label five and sees `7`

For an Array of integers `aarrayOfIntegers[3]` is sufficient which saves one level of indirection.

---

to the last snippet:

```
values = new int*[10];
```

you create an array to replace the one you just deleted.

```
*a->values = *values;
```

you assign the first element, see [Ben Voigts answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16800019/258418) and remember that an array is just a pointer to the first element. SInce you dereference it you copy the first array element. You can put these two lines into one and remove the mistake by putting:

```
a->values = new int*[10];
```

Back to your code:

```
values[0] = new int(1);
values[9] = new int(10);
std::cout << *values[0] << " " << *values[9];
```

You went through all this trouble just ot change the first and last number....

---

**TLDR, shorter solution**

Let me show you haow it can be done in a shorter way:

class TC
{
public:
    int *values;
    TC() : values(new int[10]) {}  //google initializer list
    ~TC(){ delete values; }        //destructor, called when your instance needs to be cleaned up
 };

the usage:

```
TC *a = new TC();
a->values[0] = 1;
a->values[9] =10:
std::cout << a->values[0] << " " << a->values[9];
```

or without pointers

```
TC a();
a.values[0] = 1;
a.values[9] =10:
std::cout << a.values[0] << " " << a.values[9];
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using an pointer array because this class was actually templated. Though your answer does not explain the error but it gave me the right idea what caused the error. Problem (and most importantly misunderstanding) solved.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
*a->values = *values;
```

is the same as

```
 a->values[0] = values[0];
```

But `values[0]` is uninitialized, so you don't want to be reading from it.

Comment: I am not sure how to understand your comment since the first solution works as expected. The second one is the one that makes trouble.

Comment: @kotlomoy: I expected the output of "1 10" but not the output "12341234 10" which was the output when I switched the two latter lines for the former.

Comment: Before using pointer, this pointer must point to some value. Your pointer points to some random place containing some random value. You should not expect anything predictable from random values